# How to verify an email in python without sending an email by verifying records?

Tags: python, dns, smtplib

```
import smtplib, ssl
import dns.resolver,socket

smtp_server= 'smtp.gmail.com'
port = 465
sender = 'reddy@gmail.com'
pssword = ''
addressToVerify = 'raghavareddy@smatbot.com'

context = ssl.create_default_context()

domain_name = addressToVerify.split('@')[1]
print('domain_name :  '+domain_name)
records = dns.resolver.resolve(domain_name, 'MX')
mxRecord = records[0].exchange
print(mxRecord)

host = socket.gethostname()
print('hosttttttttttt==',host)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo()
    #server.starttls(context = context)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender,pssword)
    ss = server.connect(str(mxRecord),465)
    #print(ss)
    pp = server.verify(addressToVerify)
    print(pp)
    ss = server.rcpt(addressToVerify)
    print(ss)
    print('ok')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I was trying to verify the email address but it was throwing an error while it was not connecting mxrecords

```
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond 
after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

It is not connecting to the MX records.
while verifying at

```
RCPT (503, b'5.5.1 MAIL first. p2-20020a17090ad30200b001cd4989feb7sm14376983pju.3 - gsmtp')
```

This `503` error code representing that `The server has encountered a bad sequence of commands, or it requires an authentication.

Suggest a standard way of verifying an email, please.

Answer (score 0):

> Suggest a standard way of verifying an email, please.

You can not, without sending an email with a nonce, and waiting for it to be used in some timeframe.

Servers won't let you arbitrarily test the existence of email addresses, otherwise this would be an heaven for spammers.